# How to copy the AVPicture that are received from av_read_frame. What is the right approach?

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, sdl, sdl-2

I have been trying to write a rtsp player in android. I am new to it. and wanted to know how to store the packet retrieved from av_read_frame for further usage.
[eg. **different thread to decode it** ].

```
while (1)
{

av_read_frame(pFormatCtx, &packet) >= 0) {

if (packet.stream_index == videoStream) {
           sendPacketToLInkedList ( packet);
   }  



sendPacketToLinkedList (AVPacket *pkt)
{

  AVPacket *refPacket;
  refPacket = pkt;    //  How log will it be valid ??
}
```

I just wanted to know how long the packet retrieved from av_read_frame is valid?..

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg actually has some [ok-ish documentation](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61):

> `int av_read_frame( AVFormatContext * s, AVPacket * pkt )`
>
> **If pkt->buf is NULL, then the packet is valid until the next av_read_frame() or until avformat_close_input(). Otherwise the packet is valid indefinitely**. In both cases the packet must be freed with av_free_packet when it is no longer needed. For video, the packet contains exactly one frame. For audio, it contains an integer number of frames if each frame has a known fixed size (e.g. PCM or ADPCM data). If the audio frames have a variable size (e.g. MPEG audio), then it contains one frame.

If you want `av_read_frame()`-allocated `AVPacket`s to hang around a bit longer there's always [`av_copy_packet()`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__packet.html#ga917dac9e139893510532c9bea475ef11).

Comment: Thanks for reply. if pkt->buf do u mean after execution of av_read_frame ? or before ?   so if pkt-buf is NULL, then we we need to do  av_copy_packet(), else, i do not need to copy right? Kindly correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: As I understand it, if `pkt->buf` is `NULL` *before* `av_read_frame()` (i.e., you just `memset()`ted a stack-allocated `AVPacket`) you need to `av_copy_packet()`.